# Retrieving records across 2 tables with a SUM and getting lastest record

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, count, pivot

I have a table name "claims" and "entries". The claims table is the parent and entries is the children. I'm trying to get the latest entry that was made in the claims table. Here's what my data looks like simplified:

```
Claims Table
rID     code     dateOn
1        A      2/12/2020
2        B      1/23/2020
3        A      7/11/2020
4        A      8/20/2020

Entries Table
eID     rID    type     amount
1        1     cat        5
2        3     cat        5
3        4     dog        5
4        1     dog        5
5        1     cat        2

Desired Result
code   latestCatDate    latestDogDate    DogTotal    CatTotal
A         7/11/2020        8/20/2020        10          12
```

Here's what my SQL looks like without the dates... and this works fine:

```
SELECT 
code, 
SUM(case when entries.type='cat' then entries.amount else 0.0 end),
SUM(case when entries.type='dog' then entries.amount else 0.0 end),

FROM claims c INNER JOIN entries ON entries.rID=c.rID

WHERE c.code='A'

GROUP BY code
```

I'm stuck at how to get the latestDogDate and latestCatDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add more conditional aggregate expressions to your query, like so:

```
SELECT 
    c.code, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.type = 'cat' THEN dateOn end) latestCatDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.type = 'dog' THEN dateOn end) latestDogDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.type = 'cat' THEN e.amount else 0.0 end) catTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.type = 'dog' THEN e.amount else 0.0 end) dogTotal
FROM claims c 
INNER JOIN entries e ON e.rID = c.rID
WHERE c.code = 'A'
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: Thanks... that worked perfectly. What does the MAX function do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT` and `GROUP BY`

```
with
Claims as (
    select * from (values
    (1, 'A', '2/12/2020'),
    (2, 'B', '1/23/2020'),
    (3, 'A', '7/11/2020'),
    (4, 'A', '8/20/2020')
    ) x (rID     ,code     ,dateOn)
),
Entries as (
    select * from (values
    (1,        1,     'cat',        5),
    (2,        3,     'cat',        5),
    (3,        4,     'dog',        5),
    (4,        1,     'dog',        5),
    (5,        1,     'cat',        2)
    ) x (eID     ,rID    ,type     ,amount)
),
j as (
    select c.*, e.type t2, e.eid, type, amount
    from Claims c
    join Entries e on c.rID = e.rID
),
p1 as (
    select p.code, t2, max(p.dateon) d, sum(cat) tot_cat, sum(dog) tot_dog
    from j
    pivot ( sum(amount) for type in ([cat],[dog])) p
    group by p.code, t2
),
p2 as (
    select *
    from p1
    pivot (max(d) for t2 in ([cat],[dog])) p
)
select max(code) code, max(tot_cat) tot_cat, max(tot_dog) tot_dog, max(cat) latestCatDate, max(dog) latestDogDate 
from p2
```